# Añadir background image desde javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero añadir un background image usando un link que cualquier persona puede pegar en el input, no logro saber por qué no me está funcionando el script o qué más debo de añadir para que funcione

```js
function load(){
    var img = document.getElementById("link").value;
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImg = img;
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.back{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="back">
    <input id="link" type="text" placeholder="pegar link">
    <button onclick="load()">Añadir</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>backgroundImg</del> no existe. Tienes que utilizar `backgroundImage`. Además en CSS utilizamos `background-image: url("laImagen.jpg");` y no <del>background-image:laImagen.jpg;</del>

```js
function load(){
    var img = document.getElementById("link").value;
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.back{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="back">
    <input id="link" type="text" placeholder="pegar link">
    <button onclick="load()">Añadir</button>
</div>
```